# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, lnk2019

Ok, so I'm having a problem trying figure out the problem in my code. I have a lot of code so I'm only going to post the relevant parts that are messing up when I compile. I have the following function inside of a class and it will compile and everything will run fine until I call the function "CalculateProbabilityResults" and it runs the 7th line of code within it. I've "de-commented" this line of code in my program so you can find it easier. I'm pretty sure I have the right #include directives needed since it compiles fine when not calling the function, so that can't be the problem can it? I know some of my naming notation needs a little help, so please bear with me. Thanks in advance for the help guys.

```
int SQLServer::CalculateProbabilityResults(int profile, int frame, int time_period, int TimeWindowSize) {
    ofstream ResultFile;
    stringstream searchFileName;
    stringstream outputName;
    vector<vector<int>> timeFrameItemsets;
    int num = getTimeFrameFile(frame*TimeWindowSize, TimeWindowSize);
    cout << num << endl;

    //outputName << "Results" << getTimeFrameFile((frame*TimeWindowSize), TimeWindowSize) << ".csv";
    cout << outputName.str() << endl;
    outputName.clear();
    //ResultFile.open(outputName.str().c_str());
    ResultFile.close();
    result.resize(0);
    return 0;
}

int getTimeFrameFile(int timeInHours, int timeFrameSize) {
    int fileNum = 0;
    int testWin;
    if (timeInHours > 24) {
        while (timeInHours >24)
            timeInHours -= 24;
    }
    for (testWin = 0; testWin < 24/timeFrameSize; testWin++) {
        if (timeInHours >= testWin*timeFrameSize && timeInHours < (testWin+1)*timeFrameSize)
            fileNum = testWin+1;
    }
    if (fileNum == 0)
        fileNum = testWin+1;
    return fileNum;
}
```

Call Log

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MobileSPADE_1.3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'MobileSPADE_1.3', configuration 'Debug|Win32'
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>MobileSPADE.cpp
1>SQLServer.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Compiling manifest to resources...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>Linking...
1>LINK : C:\Users\JoshBradley\Desktop\MobileSPADE_1.3\MobileSPADE_1.3\Debug\MobileSPADE_1.3.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>SQLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall SQLServer::getTimeFrameFile(int,int)" (?getTimeFrameFile@SQLServer@@QAEHHH@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall SQLServer::CalculateProbabilityResults(int,int,int,int)" (?CalculateProbabilityResults@SQLServer@@QAEHHHHH@Z)
1>C:\Users\JoshBradley\Desktop\MobileSPADE_1.3\MobileSPADE_1.3\Debug\MobileSPADE_1.3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\JoshBradley\Desktop\MobileSPADE_1.3\MobileSPADE_1.3\MobileSPADE_1.3\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>MobileSPADE_1.3 - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler thinks that getTimeFrameFile is a SQLServer method:

> unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall **SQLServer**::getTimeFrameFile(int,int)"

but you have it defined as a free function:

```
int getTimeFrameFile(int timeInHours, int timeFrameSize) {
```

Change that from a free function to a class method will solve the problem:

```
int SQLServer::getTimeFrameFile(int timeInHours, int timeFrameSize)
```

Comment: Thanks...that did the trick! I'm personally more of a theoretical person so every now and then I'll screw up and forget the syntactical things like telling the compiler which class the function belongs to lol.

Answer (score 1):

Put the function `getTimeFrameFile` above `SQLServer::CalculateProbabilityResults`.