# error LNK2019:unresolved external symbol ::FindWindow() function

Tags: c++, windows, lnk2019, visual-c++-2012

I have function findId(const QString& name) that throws me an error during coompilation:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FindWindowW@8 referenced in function "private: unsigned int__thiscall MainClass::findId(class QString const &)"(findId@MainClass@@AAEIABVQString@@@Z)

mainclass.cpp:

```
WId MainClass::findId(const QString& name)
{
  return (WId) ::FindWindow(NULL, (TCHAR*)name.utf16());
}
```

I don't know where the problem is because I have used this code before in my other project and there it worked. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: You will get better answers if you retag your question. What language? What OS? What technology? What compiler? `lnk2019` isn't a useful tag.

Comment: FindWindow requires Windows.h and User32.lib

Comment: The linker is not able to find the definition of `::FindWindow(...)`. Are you sure there is one?

Comment: I read that I have to use user32.lib, but do you know why in my other project that code works without linking it in ConfigurationProperties->Linker->Input??

Comment: Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies: `%(AdditionalDependencies)` should be in there

Comment: Duplicate of (too many to put here!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122397/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220829/lnk2019-error-unresolved-external-symbol?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297952/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318965/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol?rq=1. You want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790751/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-public)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Solution Explorer**, you have several tabs. One of the tabs is called **"Property Manager"**, open this tab. In this tab you will find your project and its configurations. What it actually contains are **Property Sheets**, one of them being **"Core Windows Libraries"**. If you right-click this one, and go to Linker->Input, you will find the Windows libraries user32.lib, etc. These properties are inherited by your project throught %(AdditionalDependencies).

One of these things is not properly set up in your current project.

Comment: A `pragma comment` is better for this case IMO.

Comment: By mistake I deleted %(AdditionalDependencies) while adding my libraries. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The linker is trying to compile your application, but cannot as it doesn't know what `FindWindow` refers to, because you haven't used the `user32` library, which is required for the [`FindWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) function.

The below code will fix it.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")    
WId MainClass::findId(const QString& name)
{
    return (WId) ::FindWindow(NULL, (TCHAR*)name.utf16());
}
```

This is worked from the code you provided and there's probably more code to it.
If so, simply `#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")` after your `#include` block, but before any of your members or namespaces.

The following sample from the [MSDN KB article on this issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) will guarantee a `LNK2019` error:

```
// LNK2019.cpp
// LNK2019 expected
extern char B[100];   // B is not available to the linker
int main() {
   B[0] = ' ';
}
```